# IAM Error while using ecs-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create a new Task for ECS using a compose file, but i'm getting an AccessDeniedException even when my user has the required permissions.

```
$ ecs-cli compose --project-name test create
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=build service name=builder
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=restart service name=db
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=restart service name=dbadmin
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=restart service name=app
ERRO[0001] Error registering task definition             error=AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:user/foo is not authorized to perform: ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition on resource: *
    status code: 400, request id: 41e6b69a-a839-11e6-84b0-e9bc2ec3f81b family=ecscompose-test
ERRO[0001] Create task definition failed                 error=AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:user/foo is not authorized to perform: ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition on resource: *
    status code: 400, request id: 41e6b69a-a839-11e6-84b0-e9bc2ec3f81b
FATA[0001] AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:user/foo is not authorized to perform: ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition on resource: *
    status code: 400, request id: 41e6b69a-a839-11e6-84b0-e9bc2ec3f81b
```

The user have this policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition",
                "ecs:ListTaskDefinitions",
                "ecs:DescribeTaskDefinition"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I also tried attaching the **AmazonEC2ContainerServiceFullAccess** (that have ecs:*), but didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried full-on power user permissions? If that still doesn't work the permission thing is probably a red herring.

Comment: i tried AmazonEC2ContainerServiceFullAccess on that user

Comment: Right, but it could be depending on some other permission and not relaying the error properly. It would at least rule permission issues out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, the user i was using had a policy to use MFA (MultiFactor Auth), that is not supported by the ecs-cli.

Comment: oh... my... god... thanks AWS =/

But an honest thanks to you, agusluc! Would have wasted a lot of time if I hadn't read this!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this posting has some answers as to why the above error is happening, thought not a fix.

[Trouble deploying docker on AWS with ecs-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191928/trouble-deploying-docker-on-aws-with-ecs-cli)

"From what I understand, ecs-cli has a very limited support of the complete Docker Compose file syntax"

per user Dolan Antenucci

Note the warnings 
"WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service..."

Comment: tried with a simplied .yml file that didn't throw any WARN, and the result was the same, AccessDeniedException

Answer (score 0):

ECS does not support a big chunk of the compose settings. However, it should just print warnings and ignore them, which will produce unintended results, but should not be throwing permission issues.

When you see 400 AccessDeniedExceptions that are in the form of "user_arn not authorized to perform service:action on service_resource" it is definitely an IAM issue. However, the IAM policy you listed looks correct. My thinking is that you are somehow not using the correct user credentials, or that the IAM policy is not applied correctly to the user.

Comment: i double checked everything, the credentials i setup for the ecs-cli tool are for my personal user, and that user have the policy listed above. I tried creating a new pair of access-key/secret-key, but the problem persist. I